# Get an array of picture filtering by themes or photographer

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a file `images.json` with this content:

```
[
  {
    "photographer": "chrysti",
    "picture": "ChristyHydeck_1.jpg",
    "themes": [
      "pets"
    ]
  },
  {
    "photographer": "chrysti",
    "picture": "ChristyHydeck_2.jpg",
    "themes": [
      "everyday",
      "pets"
    ]
  },
  {
    "photographer": "chrysti",
    "picture": "ChristyHydeck_3.jpg",
    "themes": [
      "outdoors"
    ]
  },
  {
    "photographer": "jeremy",
    "picture": "JeremyVeach_41.jpg",
    "themes": [
      "everyday",
      "pets"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to search items based on some filters (parameters passed to the function) and this is what I have:

```
static function filterImage($photographers = null, $themes = null)
{
    $images = array();
    $string = file_get_contents( "assets/main/images.json" );

    $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator( json_decode( $string, true ) ),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    );

    foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array( $val )) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($val); $i++) {
                if (in_array($val[$i], $photographers) || in_array($val[$i], $themes)) {
                    // code goes here
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "$key => $val\n";
        }
    }

    return $images;
}
```

I'm stuck trying to return an array containing current `picture` value where condition match. Lets take `chrysti` as `photographer` parameter, the output for the function should be something like:

```
$images = ["ChristyHydeck_1.jpg", "ChristyHydeck_2.jpg", "ChristyHydeck_2.jpg"];
```

Now lets do the same passing `everyday` as `themes` parameter, in this case the output should be:

```
$images = ["ChristyHydeck_2.jpg", "JeremyVeach_41.jpg"];
```

How do I get the `picture` value when condition match? Can any give me some advice for finish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
$images = array();
$string = file_get_contents( "assets/main/images.json" );
$json = json_decode($string, true);
foreach ($json as $key => $val) {
     if(in_array($val['photographer'],$photographers)){
          $images[] = $val['picture'];
     }
    foreach ($val['themes'] as $key1 => $val1){
        if(in_array($val1,$themes)){
             $images[] = $val['picture'];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Close enough... but you may double-push items if the they match both $photographers and $themes.  You should put the nested foreach into an else after the in_array.

Answer (score 0):

```
static function filterImage($photographers = null, $themes = null)
{
    $images = array();
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('assets/main/images.json',true);
    foreach ($data as $img)
    {
        if ( (in_array($img['photographer'], $photographers) 
            || (count(array_intersect($img['themes'], $themes))) )
        {
            $images[] = $img;
        }
    }
    return $images;
}
```

Comment: I got this error: `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` at this line `if ((in_array( $img['photographer'], $photographers )`

Comment: Weird.  The `json_decode($foo,true)` should have taken care of that.